# Unrecognized statement

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc

Мне нужно создать таблицу с названием snacks в бд с названием snackmachine. IDE подсвечивает красным "TABLE `snackmachine`.`snacks`". Ошибка "Unrecognized statement". Вод код:

```
public void createMainTable() {
    try {
        Statement statementCreate = connection.createStatement();
        sql = "CREATE TABLE `snackmachine`.`snacks` (" +             // тут подсвечивает
                "  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," +
                "  `category` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL," +
                "  `price` DOUBLE(10,2) NOT NULL," +
                "  `amount` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'," +
                "  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)," +
                "  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) VISIBLE)" +
                "ENGINE = InnoDB;";
        statementCreate.executeUpdate(sql);

        statementCreate.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**И вот что делать?**

Окно со свойствами подключения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какое IDE? Код работает?

Comment: Работаю в Intellij IDEA. Код отрабатывает нормально, таблицу создает. Но хочу избавиться от подчеркивания красным

Comment: Покажите окно со свойствами соединения

Comment: Прошу прощения, не понял)

Comment: Нужно подключиться к БД из IJ, для этого надо создать соединение, указать свойства, протестировать соединение. Вот это окно со свойствами соединения я и хотел посмотреть.

Comment: Добавил скрин с окном подключения в вопрос

Comment: Теперь в свойстве Database выберите `snackmachine`

Comment: Если вместо "mysql" напишу "snackmachine", то соединения не будет. Логика моей программы: когда запускаем программу, создаем бд и в ней таблицу; программа как-то там поработала и что-то позаписывала; дальше юзер вводит exit и бд удаляется.

Comment: Так что вы хотите, чтобы IJ не подчеркивала базу данных, которой нет? Уберите префикс бд из запроса.

Comment: Похоже это [известная проблема](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47599377/2231972) и, похоже, что отключить эту инспекцию [нельзя](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54693232/2231972). Можно сообщить об ошибке и надеяться, что исправят. Вообще, обычно структуру БД из java не создают. Выход - или игнорировать эти предупреждения, или не использовать плагин Database Navigator.